# Problem with \DeclareFixedFont and \psfrag in texlive2013

Tags: fonts, texlive, psfrag

I have a problem with `\DeclareFixedFont` in combination with `\psfrag` 
which occurs in texlive2013 but not in texlive2010.

When I use `\DeclareFixedFont{\myFont}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{10}` in the MWE the letter E
is positioned as expected, i.e. top-right aligned to the corner of the rectangle.

Hoewever, if I use `\DeclareFixedFont{\myFont}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}{10}` the letter is 
no longer placed correctly but shifted down and to the left. Please note, I 
do not use my new font in the `psfrag` command at all.

My current system is LinuxMint13 with texlive 2013. In my old system 
(Ubuntu 10.04 with texlive2010) the error does not show up.

I have done some further experiments on the \DeclareFixedFont-command,
which are documented in the MWE.

Moreover, if I run my "new" dvi file (created by texlive2013)
through my "old" dvips from texlive 2010 (the version ist dvips(k) 5.99),
everything is OK.

Comparing the log file output from both dvips versions, the only
significant difference I see is, that dvips(k) 5.993 from texlive2013 
also includes `texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb`, whereas dvips(k) 5.99 
does not include this file.

Is there a bug in the dvips from texlive2013 (dvips(k) 5.993)?

I have created the postcript file Rectangle.eps 
(included through filecontents environment in the MWE) using xfig 
and then exported to eps in xfig.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Rectangle.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Title: Rectangle.fig
%%Creator: fig2dev Version 3.2 Patchlevel 5d
%%CreationDate: Sat Aug 31 10:07:28 2013
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 107 70
%Magnification: 1.0000
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
/$F2psDict 200 dict def
$F2psDict begin
$F2psDict /mtrx matrix put
/col-1 {0 setgray} bind def
/col0 {0.000 0.000 0.000 srgb} bind def
/col1 {0.000 0.000 1.000 srgb} bind def
/col2 {0.000 1.000 0.000 srgb} bind def
/col3 {0.000 1.000 1.000 srgb} bind def
/col4 {1.000 0.000 0.000 srgb} bind def
/col5 {1.000 0.000 1.000 srgb} bind def
/col6 {1.000 1.000 0.000 srgb} bind def
/col7 {1.000 1.000 1.000 srgb} bind def
/col8 {0.000 0.000 0.560 srgb} bind def
/col9 {0.000 0.000 0.690 srgb} bind def
/col10 {0.000 0.000 0.820 srgb} bind def
/col11 {0.530 0.810 1.000 srgb} bind def
/col12 {0.000 0.560 0.000 srgb} bind def
/col13 {0.000 0.690 0.000 srgb} bind def
/col14 {0.000 0.820 0.000 srgb} bind def
/col15 {0.000 0.560 0.560 srgb} bind def
/col16 {0.000 0.690 0.690 srgb} bind def
/col17 {0.000 0.820 0.820 srgb} bind def
/col18 {0.560 0.000 0.000 srgb} bind def
/col19 {0.690 0.000 0.000 srgb} bind def
/col20 {0.820 0.000 0.000 srgb} bind def
/col21 {0.560 0.000 0.560 srgb} bind def
/col22 {0.690 0.000 0.690 srgb} bind def
/col23 {0.820 0.000 0.820 srgb} bind def
/col24 {0.500 0.190 0.000 srgb} bind def
/col25 {0.630 0.250 0.000 srgb} bind def
/col26 {0.750 0.380 0.000 srgb} bind def
/col27 {1.000 0.500 0.500 srgb} bind def
/col28 {1.000 0.630 0.630 srgb} bind def
/col29 {1.000 0.750 0.750 srgb} bind def
/col30 {1.000 0.880 0.880 srgb} bind def
/col31 {1.000 0.840 0.000 srgb} bind def

end

/cp {closepath} bind def
/ef {eofill} bind def
/gr {grestore} bind def
/gs {gsave} bind def
/sa {save} bind def
/rs {restore} bind def
/l {lineto} bind def
/m {moveto} bind def
/rm {rmoveto} bind def
/n {newpath} bind def
/s {stroke} bind def
/sh {show} bind def
/slc {setlinecap} bind def
/slj {setlinejoin} bind def
/slw {setlinewidth} bind def
/srgb {setrgbcolor} bind def
/rot {rotate} bind def
/sc {scale} bind def
/sd {setdash} bind def
/ff {findfont} bind def
/sf {setfont} bind def
/scf {scalefont} bind def
/sw {stringwidth} bind def
/tr {translate} bind def
/tnt {dup dup currentrgbcolor
  4 -2 roll dup 1 exch sub 3 -1 roll mul add
  4 -2 roll dup 1 exch sub 3 -1 roll mul add
  4 -2 roll dup 1 exch sub 3 -1 roll mul add srgb}
  bind def
/shd {dup dup currentrgbcolor 4 -2 roll mul 4 -2 roll mul
  4 -2 roll mul srgb} bind def
/$F2psBegin {$F2psDict begin /$F2psEnteredState save def} def
/$F2psEnd {$F2psEnteredState restore end} def

/pageheader {
save
newpath 0 70 moveto 0 0 lineto 107 0 lineto 107 70 lineto closepath clip newpath
-64.4 139.7 translate
1 -1 scale
$F2psBegin
10 setmiterlimit
0 slj 0 slc
 0.06299 0.06299 sc
} bind def
/pagefooter {
$F2psEnd
restore
} bind def
%%EndProlog
pageheader
%
% Fig objects follow
%
% 
% here starts figure with depth 50
% Polyline
0 slj
0 slc
7.500 slw
n 1035 1125 m 2700 1125 l 2700 2205 l 1035 2205 l
 cp gs col0 s gr 
/Times-Roman ff 190.50 scf sf
2542 1292 m
gs 1 -1 sc (E) col0 sh gr
% here ends figure;
pagefooter
showpage
%%Trailer
%EOF
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
% 
% latex WrongPsfragWtTexlive2013; dvips WrongPsfragWtTexlive2013 -o
%
\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag}
\listfiles
%
\begin{document}
\DeclareFixedFont{\myFont}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}{10}%        not OK
%%\DeclareFixedFont{\myFont}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{10}%        OK
%%\DeclareFixedFont{\myFont}{T1}{ptm}{\seriesdefault}{\shapedefault}{10}% not OK
%%\DeclareFixedFont{\myFont}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{\seriesdefault}{\shapedefault}{10}%  OK
%%\DeclareFixedFont{\myFont}{T1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}{10}%  OK


Some text in my new font: {\myFont Hello world}

The \verb+\DeclareFixedFont+-command has influence on the position of
the letter E in the picture although the new font \verb+\myFont+ is
not used in the \verb+\psfrag+-command.

\begin{center}
  \begin{psfrags}
    \psfrag{E}[tr][tr]{\fbox{$E$}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{Rectangle.eps}
  \end{psfrags}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons, using Times in a document where also `psfrag` is invoked creates a shift. I get no shift if I change

```
/Times-Roman
```

into

```
/Times-Bold
```

in the EPS file. Choosing a font really unused in the document might be better. See a similar problem in [Problem with psfrag + fncychap in TeXLive 2013](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197500/problem-with-psfrag-fncychap-in-texlive-2013)

Unfortunately, `psfrag` is old and unmaintained. You could switch to `pstool` that uses `pdflatex`; add

```
\usepackage{pstool}
```

to the preamble and include your picture with

```
\begin{center}
\psfragfig[width=0.35\textwidth]{Rectangle}{\psfrag{E}[tr][tr]{\fbox{$E$}}}
\end{center}
```

The `psfrag` commands can also be in an external file named `Rectangle-psfrag.tex` and in this case you just input

```
\begin{center}
\psfragfig[width=0.35\textwidth]{Rectangle}
\end{center}
```

[image]