# Problem with psfrag + fncychap in TeXLive 2013

Tags: texlive, psfrag

I am working with `psfrag` to do my plots and `fncychap` to have nice chapter titles.

[Here](http://solidosunalmzl.wikispaces.com/file/view/minimal_example.zip/519340810/minimal_example.zip) is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{psfrag}

% NOTE: 
% The error is related to \fontsize, \usefont and \selectfont
% UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING to reproduce the error withoyt the fncychap packages:
% \begin{filecontents*}{fncychap_produce_error.sty}
%  \def\@makechapterhead#1{{\fontsize{60}{62}\usefont{OT1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont 123}}
% \end{filecontents*}
% \usepackage{fncychap_produce_error}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Minimal example}
\centering
   \psfrag{dx}{$dx$}
   \psfrag{dy}{$dy$}
   \psfrag{sx}{$\sigma_x$}
   \psfrag{sy}{$\sigma_y$}
   \psfrag{txy}{$\tau_{xy}$}
   \psfrag{tyx}{$\tau_{yx}$}
   \psfrag{(a)}{(a)}
   \psfrag{(b)}{(b)}
   \psfrag{(c)}{(c)}
   \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{esfuerzos2d}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it with LATEX->DVIPS->PS2PDF, in TeXLive 2009, MikTeX 2009 I get the correct result:

[image]

However, when I compile my `.tex` files with LATEX->DVIPS->PS2PDF, in TeX Live 2013, the resulting PS and PDF files do not render well the `psfrag`ed pictures. That is:

[image]

Look that all the text is shifted to the right!!!

I have noticed that this error is produced by an incompatibility between `psfrag` and `fncychap`.

I have to stick to `psfrag` because I am writing a book with hundreds of `psfrag`ed pictures. All pics suffer the same problem.

Any clue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've rolled back the 'solved' edit: you can 'accept' egreg's answer to show it works for you, but the general format for the site doesn't encourage editing _questions_ to reflect the fact they have _answers_ (at least unless it helps guide the answers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The loading of Times done by `fncychap` conflicts with the font used by `psfrag`, which is Times as well.

The Lenny chapter style is one of the ugliest I know; using Times for the chapter number is absurd, in any case, unless Times is the main document font.

Just add

```
\ChNumVar{\normalfont\fontsize{60}{62}\selectfont}
```

to your document preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{psfrag}

\ChNumVar{\normalfont\fontsize{60}{62}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Minimal example}
\centering
   \psfrag{dx}{$dx$}
   \psfrag{dy}{$dy$}
   \psfrag{sx}{$\sigma_x$}
   \psfrag{sy}{$\sigma_y$}
   \psfrag{txy}{$\tau_{xy}$}
   \psfrag{tyx}{$\tau_{yx}$}
   \psfrag{(a)}{(a)}
   \psfrag{(b)}{(b)}
   \psfrag{(c)}{(c)}
   \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{esfuerzos2d}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, reconsider your idea of using `fncychap`.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:

In addition to the option

```
\ChNumVar{\normalfont\fontsize{60}{62}\selectfont}
```

that egreg recomended, include as well

```
\ChNameVar{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}
```

because some fonts may get lost when using psfrag.